# SSLのエラーが発生したときに、サーバ側でエラーを取得するにはどう設定(apache)したらいいのか？

Tags: apache, ssl

SSL3.0 が可能なサーバにアクセスすると、セキュリティソフトやプロクシーなどが、証明書に問題があるといってアクセスを拒否することがあります。そのログを、サーバ側で取得したいのですが、どのように設定するのがいいのでしょうか？

また、SSL3.0 を使わないサーバに、IE6 で、SSL3 のみでアクセスするとエラーになります。このログもどうも記録されないようなのです。

この種のログをきちんとできるだけ多く取得するには、どのような設定をするといいのでしょうか？

Comment: 証明書の検証はサーバー側ではなくクライアントの処理ですから、サーバーにログはありません。

Comment: サーバへアクセスはしているので、なんらかのログをとれたらとりたいのです。

Comment: どうしても検証結果の情報を取りたいならクライアント側にプラグインか何かを
入れないと無理かと…。
外部から見た検証だけなら以下の記事を参考にどうぞ 
http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fwin2k/win2ktips/1406sslchk/sslchk.html

Comment: 証明はだめのようですが、プロトコルは apache でログレベルを info にするととれるようです。

Comment: iptable で、443 を掴めば少しはなにかわかりそうです。そこまでやるかですが、

Comment: @Tadashi 確かに「SSLのハンドシェイクに失敗した」という記録はサーバー側でも取ることができると思います。ただクライアント側は理由も言わずに切断することができてしまうため、その理由はおろか、偶然なのかどうかも、サーバー側で確実な判断をするのは困難です（他の方が「無理」と言う理由はこのあたりかと）。

Comment: 理由もいわず切断したのを拾えればとりあえずいいかなというところです。データがとれれば、あとでゆっくり解析も可能です

Comment: SSLLogLevel を trace にするとハンドシェイクのトレース情報が残ると思いますがどうでしょうか。